# Does TensorFlow Serving officially support all the models from TF2.0

Tags: tensorflow-serving, tensorflow2.0

From the [release history](https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/releases) of tensorflow serving, the latest release is 1.14.0. It's using TensorFlow 1.14.0. I don't find the release version using TensorFlow 2.0. 
I'm wondering whether the TFServing of version 1.14.0 support all the models trained from TensorFlow 2.0?
Or is there any schedule to release the TFServing 2.0?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stackoverflow!

According to [this issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/25363) TF Serving should be compatible with TF 2.0 by now as it has been marked "done". It might not be in the official packages yet, though.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer. It seems that there is a compatibility [issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/issues/1462) if the model uses *tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_vocabulary_list*.